# Convert all unicode characters to a specific character

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005, unicode

Is there any way to tell if a character isn't an Extended-ASCII character?

If so, I would like to be able to make that character a '?'

If I tried to insert a Unicode character into a varchar in SQL Server 2005, what would happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create string with all allowable characters (letters, digits, whitespaces, your national accented characters etc) and check every character if it is in this string. If not, then replace it with '?'.

Comment: Could I not just use a regular expression?

Comment: Yes, you can! Simply create string of allowable characters then create regex: `"[^"+ALLOWABLE+"]"` and use it to replace all matching characters into '?'